# using a backbone model to fill options of a select field

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to populate the options of a select field with the attributes from a "static" model. For example I have a Model and a collections of US states:

```
State = Backbone.Model.extend({
    label:'',
    value:''
 }) ;
STATES = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: State
 });
 states =  [
    {label: "Select     ", value: '__' },
    {label: "Alabama     ", value: 'AL' },
    {label: "Alaska      ", value: 'AK' },
    {label: "Arizona     ", value: 'AZ' },
    ....];
  localstates = new app.STATES(states);  // or fetch the list of states from a RESTful site.
```

I then using back form have any address view and I want to pass localstates into the Form to populate the options of the state field:

```
    UserAddress =  Backform.Form.extend({
    el: $("#personalInformation"),
     fields: [
       {name: "address1", label: "Address1", control: "input"},
       {name: "address2", label: "Address2", control: "input"},
       {name: "city", label: "City", control: "input"},
       {name: "state", label: "State", control: "select", 
         options: **localstates**,
       {name: "zip", label: "Zip Code", control: "input"},
       {control: "button", label: "Save to server"}
     ],
});
```

I'm guessing I need to somehow pass the states collection into the User Address view and then access the attributes. But I have not been able to find a good example of how to do this.

edit1: Ok this is a bit silly in this case but:

```
newstate = new app.STATES(app.states);
  var allstates =[];
app.newstate.forEach(function(state){
  allstates.push({"label": state.get("label"), "value" : state.get("value")});
})
```

Gives me and array I can use at localstate. Basically I just re-created my original array in this case. In the case where it was fetch from a server it would be useful, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `localstates.toJSON()` to get a copy of the values to use in the template.

See [`Collection.toJSON()`](https://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON)

Comment: DUH! I knew there had to be a simple way.